# Is there a repeatable source of money in Roche's Chapter 3?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm replaying The Witcher 2 on dark mode. Each chapter has a special set of equipment to craft. This armor is quite powerful, but quite expensive.

With a little bit of grinding in the previous chapters, I was able to afford those armor sets. However, I didn't prepare a huge sum of money going into Chapter 3 and I can barely afford to buy the most expensive of the crafting recipes, let alone all of the pieces and materials.

Is there a repeatable source of money?

Comment: It's been a while since I played, but I remember when you first start chapter 3, there's a part where you fight harpies alongside roche (Before you get to the Order of Flaming Rose camp.) You might try going back there and seeing if they respawn. If that works I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: It sort of does... I ended up developing a route that hits that camp and a few others. Sadly there wasn't anything I found that was like Act 2's nearly instant harpy respawns or farming arm wrasslin'. The Act 3 harpies seem to have a much longer respawn time